# Интересное это слово — «капибара»/капибара

Tags: кавычки

Нужна кавычки?

> Интересное это слово — **«капибара»**.

Answer (score 0):

Напишем так:

**Интересное это слово — *капибара*.**

**Кавычки** нужны для выделения малоизвестных слов, но в данном случае — это тема текста. Но как-то выделить слово желательно. Кавычки возможны, но необязательны. Обойдемся **курсивом.**
**[Грамота](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/pismovnik/v-kakikh-sluchayakh-nuzhny-kavychki)**

**Из Википедии:**

**Капиба́ра, или водосви́нка** (лат. Hydrochoerus hydrochaeris), — полуводное травоядное млекопитающее из подсемейства водосвинковых (Hydrochoerinae), один из двух (наряду с малой водосвинкой) ныне существующих видов рода водосвинки. Капибара — самый крупный среди современных грызунов.

**Название** животного берёт начало от слова ka’apiûara, что на мёртвом языке тупи (родственном языку индейцев гуарани) буквально означает **«поедатель тонкой травы»** (kaá (трава) + píi (тонкий) + ú (есть) + ara (суффикс, аналогичный русскому суффиксу -тель))[3][4].

Comment: Но ведь нужны кавычки в *«Капибара» — это интересное слово*.

Comment: Дайте свой ответ, почему они нужны. Я обоснование написала. В "Грамоте" почитайте и выберите.